# Is there a way to force DOM focus in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, race-condition

I have some code that dynamically loads select boxes based on user selections.

I have code inside that instructs a specific option to be selected like so:

```
    //returns a string of <option>s by ID
    $('#subtopic_id').load('ajax.php?f=newSubtopic&topic_id=' + id);
    $('#subtopic_id').removeAttr('disabled');
    alert('hi');
    $('#subtopic_id').val(66); //forces SELECT box to show a specific option
```

However, it only works when I have `alert('hi');` present in the above code.  When I remove the `alert` line, the select box that tries to force the selection 66 does not appear to work.

What could be going wrong?  I can only imagine that `alert` somehow grabs the focus, or maybe introduces a delay or does some other magic which makes the next line work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `load()` is asynchronous, therefore you need to provide a callback function to be executed when the AJAX request completes and the content has been placed in the DOM. Only then can you set your required `val()`. Try this:

```
$('#subtopic_id').load('ajax.php?f=newSubtopic&topic_id=' + id, function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', false).val('66');
});
```

Comment: thanks, that works!  so otherwise the request was not completing in time for the value change?

Comment: That's correct. You were basically ordering a pizza and trying to eat it before it was delivered. With async code you have to use the callback pattern.